# Load balancing ISPs without double NAT

Tags: networking, web-server, load-balancing, local-area-network, isp

I configures my TP-Links ER605 multi-wans router to load balance between my two ISPs (that is working).  But since my Web/NAS server is behind my router on the 192.168.2.0 network, any computers on 192.168.0.0 and 192.168.1.0 can't access the NAS or Web server directly.  The ER605 won't let use the same subnet on the the lan and the two wan.

I look at these 4 questions but no luck.

[load balancing isps on ubuntu server](https://serverfault.com/questions/392183/load-balancing-isps-on-ubuntu-server)
[load-balancing NATing multiple isp on linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/93678/load-balancing-nat-ing-multiple-isp-connections-on-linux)
[load balance ecmp two isps and three routers](https://serverfault.com/questions/1048902/load-balance-ecmp-two-isps-and-three-routers)
[dual isps load balancing](https://serverfault.com/questions/325023/dual-isps-load-balancing)

I try static route on my two ISP gateways and on my router to reroute trafic but my Web pages and windows share drives are not accessible except from 192.168.2.0 network.

I am **not** trying to make my server visible/accessible from the internet, only from any of my local network.  Any help, config wise or by changing my network setup would be appreciated.

[Image: Network Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEWm4.png)

Comment: Why won't you move everybody behind this TP-Link router? I.e. don't use those 192.168.0.0/24 and 192.168.1.0/24 networks at all, for nothing. Shut down their wireless. Put everybody into 192.168.2.0/24. Add a wireless AP into this network if you need it. Also, if you want to split LAN users and servers & NAS, *both* networks should be managed by your TP-Link.

Comment: This would work but I would lose redundancy.  Primary goal is to have access to the internet all the time (DSL, Cable & on my phone worst case scenario).  If ISP-1 is down, a switch or a router fail, I can wifi to one of other ISP.  What I am after is a nice to have option to access the servers regardless of my local access point but my ER605 won't let me flatten my network (or I don't know how)

Comment: Right now you already don't have any redundancy for servers. You'll inevinably lose access to them if TP-Link fails. If such failure concern you that much, estimate how probable is this router failure? If cost of the failure looks substantial for you (more than the price of the redundancy), better buy a replacement for the router, configure it and let it rest at the shelf, or, if it supports things like VRRP you may set it up running and have automatic handover in the event of the failure. But I strongly advise you to build all user networks behind this single logical router.

Comment: I only have a small number of user and redundancy for server access is easily fix with the addition of a wifi access point on 192.168.2.0 as you rightly pointed out.  When I bought the TP-Links ER605, I was under the impression that I could use it in router mode but it only support Gateway mode and NAT can not be turned off (Wrong Hardware for my need).  tks for the help and advises.

Answer (score 1):

As Nikita rightfully pointed out there is no Servers redundancy and access is easily fixed with the addition of a wifi access point on 192.168.2.0

I bought the TP-Links ER605 under the impression that I could use it in router mode but it only supports Gateway mode and NAT can not be turned off without an open-source firmware upgrade (**Wrong Hardware** for my need).

The **best solution** is to replace/remove the TP-Link (ER605) and have the **server or a new router** for **DHCP** and **load balancing** between the two ISPs with all users on the 192.168.2.0 network (**tks Nikita** for the solution).

Find useful code in links from the original question.

[image: Image: New Network Diagram]